# How to post multiple images to facebook timeline

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the Facebook SDK for PHP (version 4).

I need to upload multiple images for 1 post in timeline (with albums type is 'data')

This is my code which runs OK for 1 image:

```
// Get albumID
...........
// Post
$data = array(
  'source' => new CURLFile(realpath($image), 'image/png'),
  'message' => $title . " \n" . $content . " \n"  . $price
);
$response = new Facebook\FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'POST', '/' . $albumId . '/photos', $data
)->execute()->getGraphObject();
```

Please help me how to upload multiple images for 1 post.